# How to change the size of legend in PointLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending, visualization

```
data = Get["http://t.cn/RSzJjcb"];
ListPlot[Values[data], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Keys@data, LegendMarkerSize -> 10]]
```

[image]

But the the size of legend is too small.I try `LegendMarkerSize -> 50` but not works.

But in the doc,this really works,so how to deal with it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you explicitly define the list of colors as the first argument of `PointLegend`. (`ColorData[97]` is the default color scheme.)

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[Keys@data]];

ListPlot[Values[data],
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[colors, Keys@data, LegendMarkerSize -> 20]
 ]
```

EDIT: You don't event have to explicitly define the list of colors, only its `ColorData` number.

```
ListPlot[Values[data],
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, Keys@data, LegendMarkerSize -> 20]
 ]
```

[image: plot]